# How many $(a,b)\in\Bbb Z^+\times\Bbb Z^+$ are there so that $(a,b)\mathrel{S}(n,n)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Let $n \in \mathbb Z^+ = \{1,2,3,\dots\}$. 
How many $(a,b) \in \mathbb Z^+ \times \mathbb Z^+$ 
are such that, $(a,b)S(n,n)$ where

$$(a,b)S(c,d) \iff a + b ≤ c + d$$

In our case, $(a,b)S(n,n) \iff a + b ≤ 2n$

I have found that for $n = 1$, then there is only one ordered pair, which is $(1,1)$.

For $n = 2$, there are $6$ ordered pairs.

For $n = 3$, there are $15$ ordered pairs.

I can't seems to find the pattern. Is my approche to this questions correct?

Answer (score 1):

First let me correct your terminology: for $n=2$, for instance, what you mean is that there are $6$ **ordered pairs** that are in the relation $S$ to $(2,2)$. The objects $(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(1,3)$, and $(3,1)$ that you found are ordered pairs, not relations.

HINT: For a given $n$ you’re counting the pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a+b\le 2n$. One way to do that is to count the pairs with each possible sum up through $2n$ and add up the results. The smallest possible sum is $2$, from the pair $(1,1)$, and that’s the only pair with sum $2$. Let’s make a table showing the pairs with a given sum and see if any pattern emerges:

$$\begin{array}{c|l}
n&\text{pairs with that sum}\\ \hline
2&(1,1)\\
3&(1,2),(2,1)\\
4&(1,3),(2,2),(3,1)\\
5&(1,4),(2,3),(3,2),(4,1)
\end{array}$$

- Spot the pattern in this table and prove that it’s really there.
- Then use that pattern to find a formula in term of $n$ for the number of $(a,b)\in\Bbb Z^+\times\Bbb Z^+$ such that $a+b\le 2n$.

Comment: For when n = 5, did you mean to say (1,5),(2,3),(3,2),(5,1) instead of (1,5),(2,3),(3,2),(4,1)?

Comment: @00111000: No, the $(1,5)$ was a typo for $(1,4)$, which I’ve now fixed. Thanks.

Comment: The pattern in the table is that there is always n-1 pairs, but how do I use it to find what I need?

Comment: @00111000: If $n=4$, say, you know that you’ll have $1$ pair with a total of $2$, $2$ with a total of $3$, $3$ with a total of $4$, and so on up through $7$ with a total of $8$. Thus, you’ll have $$1+2+3+4+5+6+7$$ pairs. Do you know a formula for the sum of the first so many positive integers (or for the sum of an arithmetic progression)?

Comment: Why did you say that "you'll have 1 pair with a total of 2"?, what pair would that be? Are you talking about 2n in this case?

Comment: And no, I don't know the formula for the sum of an arithmetic progression.

Comment: @00111000: The pair with a total of $2$ is the pair $(1,1)$. In fact, the ten pairs with totals $2$ through $5$ are shown in the table that I made. \\ I’m a bit surprised that you’ve not seen the formula $$\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac{n(n+1)}2\;;$$ at any rate, it’s one that you definitely need to know.

Comment: You want the sum $1+2+3+ \dots +2n$

Comment: @Steven: No, I wanted the general formula.

Comment: @00111000: You’re welcome.